# Can a [FromBody] object have functionality?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, rest

I've got a controller that accepts the object:

```
    /// <category>Location Operations</category>
    /// <name>Search by SearchObject</name>
    [Route("Location/Search", Name = "LocationSearch")]
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Entity> LocationSearch([FromBody] SearchObject searchObject)
    {
        var location = _locationService.Search(searchObject).ToList();
        return location;
    }
```

I have defined the SearchObject as:

```
public class SearchObject
{
    /// <summary>   Initializes a new instance of the Omnia360.ProductApi.Model.Locations.SearchObject class. </summary>
    public SearchObject()
    {
        this.SearchTerms = new List<SearchTerm>();
    }

    /// <summary>   Gets or sets the name of the entity. </summary>
    /// <value> The name of the entity. </value>
    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>   Gets or sets the search terms. </summary>
    /// <value> The search terms. </value>
    public IList<SearchTerm> SearchTerms { get; set; }
}
```

**Is this a valid definition, or does an object that will be used as `[FromBody]` need to have only a `{get;set;}` and no functionality whatsoever?**

Comment: dont know if it's relevant, but the user will pass in a json object into a GET request

Comment: The deserializer will use the default constructor to new-up an instance, then set properties. It's possible that the list you assign in the constructor might be replaced by the deserializer setting the same property.

Comment: a GET will ignore the body